# GCP Compute Engine Resource Not Available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have 4 vm instances in South-Asia region in two zones (south-asia-a & south-asia-c) out of three. I can't boot up all four instances due to below error regarding resources not available in current zone or region.

I can't move instances to other region, because public IP will change, in South-Asia region all zones shows same error.

Even tried to create new instance in different zone like south-asia-b, but same error.

> The zone 'projects/some-projectname/zones/asia-south1-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

**EDIT: Tried all three zones a,b,c of asia-south.**

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have face the same issue. I ended up switching to `asia-south1-c`. This is a recent error. I first encountered 1.5 weeks ago. If you `must` use `asia-south1-a` then you can raise a support ticket. Anyway, the issue should be fixed soon since many users are facing the same problem.

Comment: Have instance in that all three zones of south-asia region, but neither booting up nor can create new one, shows same error only.

Comment: Seems problem has escalated. I checked right now and I am still having issue with `asia-south1-a` but I can create vm in `asia-south1-c`. I suggest you raise a support ticket.

Comment: I tried to create new vm instances in all three zones but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have snapshots of the instances disks you can use the snapshots as an existing disk to create new instances in any region/zone. If you do not have a snapshot you cannot create now since the instance has to be running to do so.

Edit:
We are continuously adding more and more resources to avoid situations like this. If your workload is predictable long term, you may want to purchase [commitment and reserve](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts?hl=en_US#combining_reservations_with_commitments) the resources you will use at a discount price.

Comment: Instances are in stop stag and I am willing to start it, I tried all three available zone in South-Asia region, but no luck. Can't change region because it will required to change External IPs, which I can't afford as my app vendor charge me to change in app so.

Comment: Edited my answer with an additional solution.

Comment: Yes, that is good suggestion for commitment, I will work out it on later stage, but right now can't boot up vm instances.

Comment: Still no resolution from GCP, its since two days throwing same error, I think did a mistake by migrating my resources from Other Cloud Infra Provider to GCP.

Comment: Pls help here, still can't spin up my instances.

Comment: Try and move your instances to another zone in asia-south1 and try to start it. Use this as a guide: stackoverflow.com/a/45126763/9243066

Comment: I tried all three zones asia-south1-a, b & c, msg "does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request" for n1-highcpu-4 (4 vCPUs, 3.6 GB memory), even try E2 also, but same.

Comment: I see. Can't you use smaller machines with fewer CPUs than n1-highcpu-4? You have a higher chance to get the resources that way.

Comment: I tried for n1-highcpu-2 (2 vCPUs, 1.8 GB memory) also, but no luck, and get below it.

Comment: I have reported the same issue 1 month back. Still no luck. Planning to move to a better cloud provider.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157389814